# Node Fonttools - undefined symbol: Py_Initialize

Tags: python, c, node.js, ttx-fonttools

I am using the npm module [fonttols](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fonttools) - https://github.com/dfrankland/node-fonttools in my NodeJS application.

Everything is working fine in my local development environment (Mac) but when I try to start my application in an ubuntu based docker image on amazon EC2 I got the following error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /srv/api/node_modules/fonttools-test/build/Release/fonttools.node: undefined symbol: Py_Initialize
```

I have python installed on my docker image.

I've also created a GitHub issue about it: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dfrankland/node-fonttools/issues/5)